# How can I do tweetnacl.sealedbox.seal without Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to recreate this function in javascript:

```
tweetnacl.sealedbox.seal(new Uint8Array(n[0]), w); // w is a parseKey
```

https://github.com/dchest/tweetnacl-js

I have found a port in JS but it requires Node.js and I am interested in doing it in a browser way if I use Node.

Is there something already done? I haven't found it.

Comment: This seems to be a browser version: https://github.com/whs/tweetnacl-sealed-box/blob/master/sealedbox.web.js

Comment: Yes, I tried that website but your own example gives an error, it says that sealedbox is not defined: / https://jsfiddle.net/2hktde1y/

Comment: what's with this question? You have the power to delete your own posts, if that was your intent here.

Comment: based on the edit, there is no actual question here: the code you show only calls `tweetnacl.sealedbox.seal`, it does not show any recreation of that function by you, nor do you explain what you expect to happen here. As for finding a Node.js only version: that shouldn't be a problem? Run it through a browser-build using webpack, or browserify, or (etc) and then use the result?

Comment: Also, the github project you link to says it's for the browser and node, so if you can't figure out how to use it in the browser based on the documentation: _[file an issue](https://github.com/dchest/tweetnacl-js/issues/new) to ask the maintainers to ammend the documentation_. If you can't find it, presumably others can't, either, so be part of the solution for everyone, not just yourself =)  (especially if this is so important to you that you've put more than half your rep up as bounty. Ask the people directly involved, first. SO is your last resort, which is clearly not the case here yet)

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`tweetnacl-sealedbox-js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tweetnacl-sealedbox-js) package and the web version that you can find on JSDeliver CDN [`sealedbox.web.js`](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tweetnacl-sealedbox-js@1.2.0/sealedbox.web.js).

Run the code snippet (*which is based on your [jsFiddle snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/2hktde1y/)*) to see it in action:

```js
const buffer = new Uint8Array([1,2,3,4,5]);
const keyPair = nacl.box.keyPair();
const sealed = sealedBox.seal(buffer, keyPair.publicKey);
const result = sealedBox.open(sealed, keyPair.publicKey, keyPair.secretKey);

document.getElementById('sealed').textContent = sealed;
document.getElementById('decrypted').textContent = result;
```

```html
<script src="https://tweetnacl.js.org/nacl.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tweetnacl-sealedbox-js@1.2.0/sealedbox.web.js"></script>

<h2>Sealed</h2>
<pre id="sealed"></pre>

<h2>Decrypted</h2>
<pre id="decrypted"></pre>
```